# Validating mysql query for record existence

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code to test whether record is present or not.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    return;
}

$userid=100000306995504;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select url from userpost  where userid ='".$userid."' LIMIT 1 ");
$bool = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    
if($bool['url'])
{
    echo 'yes';
}
else
    echo 'no';
```

But even though the record is present in the table, the result is `No`.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What this says `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: if you write `print_r($bool)` what does it says? You can have a value equal 0 from db, that's why you get `no`

Comment: Is the userid numeric or text?  If numeric, why do you have single quotes?

Comment: @DanBracuk: username is numeric

Comment: perhaps you should remove  quotes just try like this....where userid =$userid... double quotes will parse the userid variable

Comment: @viakondratiuk: `print_r($bool)` shows nothing

Comment: Or it may failed connection , you should echo some text when connection fails

Comment: @user123 at php empty value is converted to false, that's why you are getting `No`. What `mysqli_num_rows ` says?

Comment: does this extraordinary user ID exist in your database...?

Comment: @Tomazi: yes it exist. it was working fine but suddently it has stopped working. wamp server is running